# MinGW x64 Adding 'A' to end of member function

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

I have the following code:

```
// --- message_queue.hpp ---
namespace vca {
namespace keystone {
namespace messaging {
class VCA_KEYSTONE_DLL_PUBLIC MessageQueue final {
  [...]
  Message PeekMessage();  // <-- Declaration
  [...]
};
}  // namespace messaging
}  // namespace keystone
}  // namespace vca

// --- message_queue.cpp ---
namespace vca {
namespace keystone {
namespace messaging {
Message MessageQueue::PeekMessage() {  // <-- Definition
  [...]
}
}  // namespace messaging
}  // namespace keystone
}  // namespace vca
```

I get the following strange error from `MinGW-builds-4.8.1-x64-posix-seh`:

```
..\..\lib\messaging\src\message_queue.cpp:281:35: error: no
'vca::keystone::messaging::Message vca::keystone::messaging::MessageQueue::PeekMessageA()'
 member function declared in class 'vca::keystone::messaging::MessageQueue'
 Message MessageQueue::PeekMessage() {
                                  ^
```

The thing that confuses me is why it is saying the `PeekMessageA()` function doesn't exist, where did the `A` come from?

If I remove the definition, it will compile and I will get the expected linker errors:

```
lib\messaging\src\task.cpp.1.o: In function
  `vca::keystone::messaging::Task::TaskImpl::PeekMessageA()':
    ../../lib/messaging/src/task.cpp:939:
    undefined reference to `vca::keystone::messaging::MessageQueue::PeekMessageA()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This shows that the `A` is added to the `Task::TaskImpl::PeekMessageA`.  What is this `A` and why is `gcc` not finding the compiling the correct symbol when I build my file?

Comment: Unfortunately, you hit one of winapis macros. The [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is expanding to `PeekMessageA`

Comment: @JesseGood, thanks, just worked that out before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows API provides two versions of many functions, one for **A** NSI-encoded and one for **W** ide strings. Typically, a compiler option and set of header macros will map the undecorated names to either of the two versions, as well as provide suitable definitons ofthe `TEXT` and `_T` macros.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  This error occurs when I use `boost::thread` instead of `std::thread`, could that have an effect?  I guess [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407) is the MSDN articale.

Comment: @MattClarkson: I don't know, but I'd look at the MingW documentation rather than at Boost. It should explain how to select the string mode.

Comment: Haha, worked it out - bloody Microsoft.  So WIN32 API has a [`PeekMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943) which will have a `#define PeekMessage PeekMessageA`.  This will replace my function declaration.  Due to a [regression in boost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/4849/interlocked.diff) I have to include `Windows.h` to get boost interlocked to work on MinGW x64.  Problem solved, thanks for the tip ;)